# PowerShell Getting All Users From Multiple Groups

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am trying to do a for each group get users. and then get more details on the users.

Can someone see why the below is not working ?

```
 do 
    {

$Group=@('"Group1"'
        '"Group2"',
        '"Group3"',
        '"Group4"',
        '"Group5"')

 try{
        $Group | ForEach{
    ForEach ($member in (Get-ADGroupMember $_ ))
    {
    $user = Get-ADUser $member -Properties *
    $useracc = $user.samaccountname
    $userid = $user.EmployeeID
    $userout = $useracc + "    -    " + $userid
    write-output $userout | out-file -filepath c:\temp\New.txt -Append -NoClobber
    }
    }
    }
    Catch
        {
    write-output $userout | out-file -filepath c:\temp\error.txt            }


    }
until ($memeber -eq $Null)
```

Comment: At the very least you are missing 3 closing brackets, and from all I can tell you are not outputting anything just assigning $user to each user one by one, and not outputting it at all.

Comment: thats only a snipit it's all closed of correctly and there is more to follow witch catch's.

Comment: At the very least change the `ForEach` loop so that you are not re-using `$user` so `ForEach($user in (get-adgroupmember $_))` becomes `ForEach($member in (get-adgroupmember $_))` and then change `$user = Get-ADUser $user -prop *` to specify the distinguishedname property like `$ADUser = Get-ADUser $member.distinguishedname -prop *` ...see if that helps.

Comment: It is a good practice to give us code we can use so that we can repeat it instead of making us fix small mistakes just so we can test.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician You might as well make your comment an answer

Comment: Added A rewritten sample code, which reproduces the same error.

Comment: There is a missing `Until`/`While` clause for your `Do` as well. Guessing that it might not matter. Thanks for the updates all the same :)

Comment: opps forgot to copy that across

Comment: You say it reproduces the same error. What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's start off with, your `Do{}Until()` loop is pointless, at least in the example code you gave. Next, you should be a bit less global on your `Try/Catch`. I avoid putting `ForEach` loops within `ForEach-Object` loops, because it really gets hard to keep track of things, but that's me.

So, what you have above functions. I replaced "'Group1'" with the distinguishedname of a group in my domain that I'm a member of, ran your code as is, and it output the file expected. There is no reason that it would not work with multiple groups. It was kind of slow, but I attribute that to the way the script was written. I re-wrote it a bit, and this should do the same thing, but faster, and with slightly better error handling:

```
$Groups=@('"Group1"'
    '"Group2"',
    '"Group3"',
    '"Group4"',
    '"Group5"')
ForEach($Group in $Groups){
    Try{
        Get-ADGroupMember $Group | Where {$_.objectClass -eq 'user' } | Select -expand distinguishedName | Get-ADUser -Properties EmployeeID | ForEach {
            "{0}`t-`t{1}" -f $_.samaccountname, $_.employeeid | Add-Content C:\Temp\New.txt
        }
    }
    Catch{
        "Error getting members for $Group" | Add-Content C:\Temp\Errors.txt
    }
}
```

Comment: Prefect, i think i just got lost within my Foreach like you explain,
I made some small edits but for mine and added a little more, there is a small typo in your eaxmple, The array should be Groups, not Group.

Comment: Right you are, that was a type (I used an actual group so I didn't copy/paste that part from my PowerShell, I just snagged it from your example). I have updated the answer, thanks for catching it!